# How do I know what types of float to use?

Tags: python, numpy, types, floating-point, precision

My question is: **Given a float point number, what is the minimal type in `numpy` in order to hold it?** Consider the flowing example:

```
dt = datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 1, 17, 32, 53, 966819)
dt_unix = dt.timestamp()
print(dt_unix)
print(np.float32(dt_unix))
print(np.float64(dt_unix))
print(np.finfo(np.float32).precision)
```

The output is:

```
1533115973.966819
1533116000.0
1533115973.966819
6
```

Obviously, `np.float32` seems not able to hold it, but how do I know that in previous? After all, the suggested precision is 6. So in general, what is the range of a particular type, e.g.  `np.float32`, and what *real* precision is that type.

Comment: These specifications are listed in [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html).  A `float32` includes a sign bit, 8 bits exponent, and 23 bits mantissa.

Comment: I still don't mean the meaning, can you put it in plain language or some mathematical form? `8 bits exponent` means what? `23 bits mantissa` corresponding to? and what does `np.finfo(np.float32).precision` means?  @user3483203

Comment: https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~eedwards/compsys/float/ It's how floating bit numbers are stored.

Comment: @user3483203 Ok, let me dig into these, and hope can get the range and float point precision from these.

Comment: You seem to be asking, what numpy floating point datatype is big enough to hold a POSIX timestamp to millisecond precision. That requires 17 significant digits decimal, which is at (but for dates in the reasonably immediate future, probably within) the limit of accuracy of `numpy.float64`. But if you do arithmetic on dates then expect some roundoff in the last digit. For an explanation of *mantiss* and *exponent* see the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754. It's a lot to explain in a StackOverflow response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Integers

[`np.finfo`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.finfo.html) gives various information about data types. I find `epsneg` the most convenient to use here: it is the smallest number x such that 1-x has a representation distinct from 1. Integers N can be represented accurately for as long as N and N-1 are distinct. This means the upper bound for **integers** that fit into a floating point format is `1/epsneg`:

```
print(1/np.finfo(np.float16).epsneg)  # 2048
print(1/np.finfo(np.float32).epsneg)  # 16777216
print(1/np.finfo(np.float64).epsneg)  # 9007199254740992
print(1/np.finfo(np.float128).epsneg) # 18446744073709551616
```

#### Floating point numbers

This is more complicated, because most real numbers, like `0.1`, are not precisely represented in any floating point format that NumPy has. We can try the most precise of the available formats first, and then check if it's still represented in the same way by a smaller format.

```
>>> x = np.float128('0.9764404296875')
>>> np.float64(x) == x
True
>>> np.float32(x) == x
True
>>> np.float16(x) == x
False
```

So, this number is precisely represented by float32, but not by float16.

Then again, this is mostly theoretical because if that number was not specifically created for this demo, we would probably get False every time: all floating point representations are likely to involve roundoff errors.